# bot rpa python-sqlserver-php

Tags: python, bots, rpa

I need to implement 3 logics to a bot that was made in python with selenium.
Tried to implement the following logics:

1. Add A Try Catch In The Main Class. In The Testt.py File In The Last Line When The WhileInit Function Is Called, In The Catch Put A Function So That The Bot Restarts (Do It With .bat File).
2. Modify the option when it jumps to error, do not restart the browser, close the other pages and validate if it is logged in correctly, if it is logged in GAC, continue again with the following case.
3. Change Logic of Taking Cases, When the Bot Takes a Case It Must Perform a Double Validation to be able to Take the Case

Tried to implement the following logics:

code:

```
from auto.init import FileInit
from auto.GAC.login import LoginGAC
from auto.driver import InitDriver
from auto.GAC.activate_number import ActivateNumeric
from auto.GAC.update_data import UpdateData
from auto.UDB.verify_UDB import Verify
from auto.GAC.tipificacion import Tipificacion
from auto.GAC.tipificacion_post import TipificacionPost
from auto.GAC.sms import SMSMessage
from auto.GAC.login_auto import LoginAuto
from auto.PVL.unlocked_sale import Unlocked
from auto.GAC.Sms_prom import Smsprom
from auto.GAC.tipificacion_smsprom import tipificacionpostpre


from db. procedures import *
#from db. update import verification
import time
import os
import sys

__version__ = 1.16

class FunctionActivate:
    def __new__(self, data_info, driver, id_bot):
        ParteProceso = 0
        number_real = ""
        number_confirmation = ""
        data = ""
        number_request = ""
        tipi_msmprom=""
        try:
            inicio = time.time()
            status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            ParteProceso = data_info[30]
            if ParteProceso == None or ParteProceso == "":
                ParteProceso = 0
            if ParteProceso <= 1:
                ParteProceso = 1
                number_real = ActivateNumeric(id_bot,data_info[1], data_info[3], data_info[4], data_info[5], data_info[6], data_info[7], data_info[8], data_info[9], data_info[10],data_info[33])
                update_numer_real(number_real, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
               

            if number_real == "" or number_real == None:
                number_real = data_info[2]

            if ParteProceso <= 2:
                ParteProceso = 2
                number_confirmation, PlanTarifario = UpdateData(id_bot, number_real, data_info[3], data_info[4], data_info[5], data_info[6], data_info[7], data_info[8], data_info[9], data_info[10], data_info[11],data_info[31],data_info[32])
                update_numer_confirmation(number_confirmation, data_info[0]) 
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
             
            if number_confirmation == "" or number_confirmation == None:
                number_confirmation = data_info[13]
                #tipifiacion de mensajes promocionales

            if ParteProceso <= 3:
                ParteProceso = 3
                tipi_msmprom=tipificacionpostpre(id_bot,number_real,data_info[33], "PREPAGO",data_info[34])
                update_tipifiacion_mensajeria(tipi_msmprom,data_info[0])
                ##CAMBIAR update_numer_request(number_request, data_info[0]) #crear nuea columna en DB y almacene tipificacion
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            if tipi_msmprom== "" or data == None:
                tipi_msmprom=data_info[35]     

            if ParteProceso <= 4:
                ParteProceso = 4
                data = Verify(driver, number_real, id_bot, 'PREPAGO')
                update_OSK_BOSK_EQOSID(data, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            
            if data == "" or data == None:
                data = [data_info[22], data_info[23], data_info[24]]

            if ParteProceso <= 5:
                ParteProceso = 5
                number_request = Tipificacion(id_bot, number_confirmation, data[0], data[1], data[2], number_real)
                update_numer_request(number_request, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            
            if number_request == "" or number_request == None:
                number_request = data_info[14]

            if ParteProceso <= 6:
                ParteProceso = 6
                SMS_message = SMSMessage(id_bot, number_request, number_real,tipi_msmprom,data_info[12],data_info[33])
                update_sms_message(SMS_message, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            ParteProceso = 6
            print('Envio SMS - OK')

            fin = time.time()
            fin = int(fin - inicio)
            update_TMO(fin, data_info[0])
            status_bot('Inactivo',id_bot)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            NameError = 'Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(e).__name__, e
            print(NameError)

            status_bot('Error en los aplicativos', id_bot)
            update_error(data_info[0], ParteProceso)
            print('Error en los aplicativos')
            return False
        

class FunctionActivatePost:
    def __new__(self, data_info, driver, id_bot):

        SoloPruebas = "SoloPruebas" #cambiar para caso real

        ParteProceso = 0
        PlanTarifario = ""
        number_confirmation = ""
        data = ""
        number_request = ""
        ObservacionesForError = ""
        MsgPeticion=""
        tipi_msmprom=""
        try:
            inicio = time.time()
            status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            number_real = data_info[2]
            ParteProceso = data_info[30]
            if ParteProceso == None or ParteProceso == "":
                ParteProceso = 0

            if SoloPruebas == "SoloPruebas":
                number_real = "61295414"

            if ParteProceso <= 1:
                ParteProceso = 1
            number_confirmation, PlanTarifario = UpdateData(id_bot, number_real, data_info[3], data_info[4], data_info[5], data_info[6], data_info[7], data_info[8], data_info[9], data_info[10], data_info[11],data_info[31],data_info[32], "POSTPAGO", ParteProceso)
            if number_confirmation == "" or number_confirmation == None:
                number_confirmation = data_info[13]
            update_numer_confirmation(number_confirmation, data_info[0])
            status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            if number_confirmation == "" or number_confirmation == None:
                number_confirmation = data_info[13]


            if ParteProceso <= 2:
                ParteProceso = 2
                if SoloPruebas == "SoloPruebas":
                    number_real = "60601360"
                status_sale = Unlocked(number_real, id_bot)
                update_status_sale(status_sale, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)

            ##MODIFICACION
            
            if ParteProceso<=3:
                ParteProceso=3

                if SoloPruebas == "SoloPruebas":
                    number_real = "61295414"
                if data_info[33] != "ACEPTA":    
                    MsgPeticion = Smsprom(id_bot, number_real, data_info[33])
                    update_comentario(MsgPeticion,data_info[0])
                    status_bot('En Gestion',id_bot)
            if MsgPeticion == "" or MsgPeticion == None:
                MsgPeticion = data_info[34]

            #TIPIFICACION DE SMS PROMOCIONALES 

            if ParteProceso <=4:
                ParteProceso=4
                if SoloPruebas == "SoloPruebas":
                    number_real = "61295414"
                if data_info[33] !="ACEPTA":    
                    tipi_msmprom=tipificacionpostpre(id_bot,number_real,data_info[33], "POSTPAGO",MsgPeticion)
                    update_tipifiacion_mensajeria(tipi_msmprom,data_info[0])
                    ##CAMBIAR update_numer_request(number_request, data_info[0]) #crear nuea columna en DB y almacene tipificacion
                    status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            if tipi_msmprom== "" or data == None:
                tipi_msmprom=data_info[35]
                


            if ParteProceso <= 5:
                ParteProceso = 5
                number_real = data_info[2]
                if SoloPruebas == "SoloPruebas":
                    number_real = "61295414"
                data = Verify(driver, number_real, id_bot, 'POSTPAGO', PlanTarifario)
                update_OSK_BOSK_EQOSID(data, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            if data == "" or data == None:
                data = [data_info[22], data_info[23], data_info[24]]

            if ParteProceso <= 6:
                ParteProceso = 6
                if SoloPruebas == "SoloPruebas":
                    number_real = "61295414"
                number_request = TipificacionPost(id_bot, number_confirmation, data[0], data[1], data[2], number_real)
                update_numer_request(number_request, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
            if number_request == "" or number_request == None:
                number_request = data_info[14]

            if ParteProceso <= 7:
                ParteProceso = 7
                SMS_message = SMSMessage(id_bot, number_request, number_real,tipi_msmprom,data_info[12],data_info[33])
                update_sms_message(SMS_message, data_info[0])
                status_bot('En Gestion', id_bot)
                

            fin = time.time()
            fin = int(fin - inicio)
            update_TMO(fin, data_info[0])
            print(fin, 'finished')
            status_bot('Inactivo',id_bot)
            return True

        except Exception as e:
            NameError = 'Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(e).__name__, e
            print(NameError)

            status_bot('Error en los aplicativos', id_bot)
            
            SendMensaje = ""

            if ParteProceso == 3:
                SendMensaje = ""
            update_error(data_info[0], ParteProceso, SendMensaje)
            print('Error en los aplicativos')
            
            return False

class WhileInit:
    def __init__(self, id_bot):
        # verification(__version__)
        FileInit()
        driver = InitDriver(id_bot).init()
        status = LoginGAC(driver, id_bot)
        if status == 'OK':
            status_bot('Login OK', id_bot)
            while True:
                data_info = select_db()
                if data_info != False:
                    
                    if data_info[12] == 'POSTPAGO':
                        status = FunctionActivatePost(data_info, driver, id_bot)
                    elif data_info[12] == 'PREPAGO':
                        status = FunctionActivate(data_info, driver, id_bot)

                    if status:
                        LoginAuto(id_bot)
                    else:
                        break

                else:
                    LoginAuto(id_bot)
                    status_bot('No hay pendientes', id_bot)
                    print('No hay pendientes')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    # verification(__version__)
        else:
            status_bot(status, id_bot)
            print(f'Estatus bot BD, {status}')
            time.sleep(5)

        # Informar que el bot está inactivo
        status_bot('Inactivo', id_bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #id_bot = input('Ingresar #Id del Bot (1 o 2):')
    print(f"Version Actual: {__version__}")
    EjecutablePrograma = os.path.basename(sys.executable)
    SearchPunto = EjecutablePrograma.find(".")
    id_bot = EjecutablePrograma[SearchPunto-1:SearchPunto]
    id_bot=1
    try:
        WhileInit(id_bot)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", str(e))
        print("Reiniciando el bot...")
        # Crear un archivo .bat para reiniciar el bot
        restart_script = """
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM python.exe
python testt.py
"""
        with open("restart_bot.bat", "w") as file:
            file.write(restart_script)
        # Ejecutar el archivo .bat para reiniciar el bot
        os.system("restart_bot.bat")
```